# How to clear Skyrim SE console

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim Special Edition on Steam. Suppose I want to clear all content on the console (without quitting to Desktop and restarting), what is the command to do so? I'm thinking of something like "cls" on Windows command prompt. I've looked around the Internet and haven't found any search results indexed by Google. Is there such a command?

Comment: I have been looking for an answer to this for years, but have not found one. Nor have I seen any mods for the same.

Comment: Can I ask why??

Comment: @kaizerwolf -- why what? If you're asking me, there are times I just want to clear clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been assured that the vanilla console simply has no documented way to clear the console. At this point, I'm considering absence of evidence proof that this is so. That being said, I learned of a mod that does have a "clear" command that does exactly that.

[More Informative Console](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/19250) for Skyrim SE. There is a lot you can do with that mod, but for me, all I have to do is type "clear" and I have what I wanted: a clear console without the clutter.

Comment: Can you link to or quote those confirmations? I've always assumed the same, but the only answer I could condense was that 'we don't know'.

Comment: Nothing written. Maybe "confirmed" isn't the right word. More like multiple people also telling me that they have not found any documented way to clear the console in the vanilla console.